# Can the Umbraco CMS be used to edit 1..* websites or just one at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

In a new existing in-house .Net  platform, we have the ability to generate pages for 1..* websites - merely by pointing to the website's root directory on the IIS server.

I would like to implement a CMS, like Umbraco to edit these 1..* websites.  Some of the pages could be similar across sites, others unique with 1..* data entry fields, etc.

is Umbraco a good candidate for this?  If so, other than the Umbraco website, where can I get more support or community feedback for Umbraco?

Thanks.

Comment: you should accept an answer, if it answers your question. If you need something elaborated, you should say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say yes, Umbraco is a pretty good candidate for that scenario :-) Umbraco supports multiple hostnames, languages, templates and it's fairly trivial to make a shared data section for all sites to use.

The official forums and documentation are on https://our.umbraco.org and there are some basic video tutorials on http://umbraco.tv (if you go the Umbraco route I can recommend signing up for the full umbraco.tv).